# Firebird's SQL's Substring function not working

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

I created a view on a machine using the *substring* function from Firebird, and it worked.  When I copied the database to a different machine, the view was broken.  This is the way I used it:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field FROM 5 FOR 15) FROM table;
```

And this is the output on the machine that does not accept the function:

```
token unknown:  FROM
```

Both computers have this configuration:

- *IB Expert* version 2.5.0.42 to run the queries and deal with the database.
- *Firebird* version 1.5 as server to database.
- *BDE Administration* version 5.01 installed, with *Interbase* 4.0 drivers.

Any ideas about why it's behaving differently on these machines?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure Firebird engine is 1.5 and there's no InterBase server running on this same box on the port you expected Firebird 1.5.
2. Make sure you don't have any UDF called 'substring' registered inside this DB so that Firebird is expecting different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Different engine versions?

Have you tried naming that expression in the result?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field FROM 5 FOR 15) AS x FROM table;
```